# Git command moves me out of current directory into parent directory

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I've been having an issue with git. When I execute a command it will push me out of the working directory and into the parent directory. This happens somewhat frequently, maybe 25% of any git command

So I will do something along the lines:

```
$user at ubuntu-machine in /var/www/project/name: git add .
$user at ubuntu-machine in /var/www/project/name: git commit -m "Git message"
$user at ubuntu-machine in /var/www/project/name: fatal: Not a git repository
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 with git version 2.7.4.

Has anyone else had this issue? Possible reasons why it's happening?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: This is not going to be helpful but it doesn't look like something I have seen in the 4 or so years I've been using git, either on GNU/Linux or Windows.

Comment: Gotcha, I am hoping someone experienced something similar. I wasn't sure what I could provide that would be helpful

Comment: 2.7.4 is more than a year old, have you tried updating? It's a rather strange problem though so I wouldn't count on it fixing anything in this regard. Sounds more like a script or a git hook does something weird.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I didn't realize I was on a much older package.

Comment: I gather that's a hand-typed example (because if not... then being pushed out of the directory isn't the problem; look at the cwd in the prompt).  Can you show actual output when this issue occurs?

Comment: Is there any alias or wrapper for the command git? What `which git` returns?

Comment: I did handwrite the example. It's a copy of what happens to me, however would work with any general git command. git checkout, git reset, etc...

Comment: I updated my git, and the issue seems to be resolved. I didn't realize that my git was out of date. I thought ubuntu packages would be up to date. I ended up doing the following to have it update to 2.11: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade git git-man"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue by updating from 2.7.4 to 2.11.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade git git-man
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks good to me as long as you initialized the directory.... if not then... you should initialize your directory first with:
git init